# Save attachments from specific sender into a specific files on computer based on certain words in the attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I want to trigger a macro when a new email from a specific email address with an .xls (sometime other) attachment is received in an inbox.

What I would like to do is the following is create a rule that:

When the sender is : `"xyz"`,

1.check for a certain word in the attachment for example : "`trade`", then save it into a certain folder.

2.If the attachment is : "`LossesOfTrades` "has another word : "`Losses`", save into another folder.

3.Format all saved files to have its name followed by the year-mm-dd 
ex: trade20150725.xls. (note that the attached file doesn't have the date in it)

4. Mark the e-mail as read.

It is important to note that some files have more than 1 attachment.

Answer (score -1):

Outlook allows to create a rule which can trigger a VBA macro where you are free to do whatever you need. The VBA sub should look like the following one:

```
Public Sub Test(mail as MailItem)
   '
End Sub
```

where the `mail` object represent the incoming message.

I'd recommend starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.

The [Attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866435.aspx) property of the MailItem class returns an Attachments object that represents all the attachments for the specified item.

The [DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862398.aspx) property of the Attachment class allows to set a string representing the name, which does not need to be the actual file name, displayed below the icon representing the embedded attachment.

For example:

```
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 'Prompt the user for confirmation 
 Dim strPrompt As String 
 strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment " & _ 
             "in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the " & _ 
             "same name already exists in the destination folder, " & _ 
             "it will be overwritten with this copy of the file." 
 If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
   myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & _ 
   myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName 
 End If
```